# Unresolved reference getValue() in kotlin (Android Studio 3)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences

I have the following piece of code for a setting page using Preferences. I can find the correct ListPreference, I can set the summary string, but I cannot get the value from the preference object. At least Android Studio cannot find the reference to the getValue() method.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat


class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar))
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_settings, MySettingsFragment())
            .commit()

    }

    class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings, rootKey)
            val pref = findPreference("selected_maptype")
            pref.summary = "This is a summary"
            val current_value = pref.getValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.value`?

Comment: I don't see getValue() here... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference

Comment: shouldn't you be calling like `pref.getDataType()`?

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` is method of [ListPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference) not [Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference), so you need to cast it.

```
val pref = findPreference("selected_maptype") as ListPreference
val current_value = pref.value
```

You will use `pref.value` instead of `pref.getValue()` in Kotlin. Kotlin changes getters setters in direct name.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin **getter** and **setter** are generally set by default so we cannot call them using **getter** and **setter** function.

An Easy way to access them is to use direct variable name with **(.)dot** operator.

You can refer this [Kotlin Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)